# change the format of date range input component

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, date-range, pentaho-cde

How to change the format of date range input component in pentaho cde.i am getting the format 'yyyy-mm-dd' but i need to change into 'dd-M-yy'.i have return a function under post execution section :

```
function()
{
var date1 = Dashboards.getParameterValue("parfromDate").toString();

var date2 = Dashboards.getParameterValue("partoDate").toString();
//alert(date1)
//alert(date2)

format = $.datepicker.formatDate("dd-M-yy",new Date(date1));

format2 = $.datepicker.formatDate("dd-M-yy",new Date(date2));


document.getElementById('render_SelectDate').value=format:format2;

}
```

the same function was working perfect in date input component but i m facing problem in date range component can any one suggest me where i m doing wrong ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have solved my issue as per need .Also i have mentioned my script which i am using right now:

```
function f(){
 var date1 = Dashboards.getParameterValue("date_param").toString();

 testdate = $.datepicker.formatDate("d-M-y",new Date(date1));
 //alert(testdate);
 document.getElementById('render_date_picker').value=testdate;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**This code also work as charm for Date Range Component**
function f(){
   var date1 = Dashboards.getParameterValue("param1_FromDate").toString();
   var date2 = Dashboards.getParameterValue("param2_ToDate").toString();

   testdate = $.datepicker.formatDate("d-M-y",new Date(date1))+">"+ $.datepicker.formatDate("d-M-y",new Date(date2));

   alert(testdate);
   document.getElementById('render_date_range_picker').value=testdate;
}
```